# Setting a variable in tcsh to a value that includes quotes and square brackets

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh, setenv

an executable expects command-line parameters in the format:

```
-varname "[64]"
```

Need to wrap it as an environment variable so the executable can be launched by another tool, so I tried:

```
> setenv PARAM '-varname "[64]"'
> echo $PARAM
echo: No match.
```

I tried all kind of escapes but couldn't find how to enclose the original string into an environment variable.

Must mention that both the inner executable and the wrapper are inflexible in their expectations, e.g. the executable expects the variable as shown and the wrapper expects a string that it associates with an environment variable through 'setenv'.

Any hint?

Thanks!

Comment: How does _the wrapper_ _tool_ actually use the variable when it lauches the _executable_? A concrete command line is more expressive than circumscriptions.

Comment: What is this wrapper actually - a script, another binary executable? And you can't modify it?

Comment: No, the wrapper is another binary tool that loads predefined environment variables. As I wrote above, neither one of the tools are modifiable.

Comment: Okay, so we don't know how the wrapper passes the arguments to the final executable. You might reveal this by executing the wrapper with `strace -feexecve …`.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting it correctly, but the problem is how the shell expands the value of $PARAM.

As you know, a star at the command line is expanded by the shell to all the files in the current directory.

```
> echo *
```

The result of shell expansion is subsequently used as the argument to `echo`.

There are additional wildcard/glob patterns allowed at the command line.  Square brackets define character class.
To echo all files containing either a `4` or a `6`:

```
> echo *[46]*
```

To echo all files named *exactly* 4 or 6.

```
> echo [46]
```

In the above example, if no files are named exactly 4 or 6, then you'll get `echo: No match.`

###### Solution:  use printenv

```
> setenv PARAM '-varname "[64]"'
> printenv PARAM
   -->  -varname "[64]"
```

Note that `PARAM`, not `$PARAM` is the argument to `printenv`.   This avoid shell expansion of `$PARAM`.